# PTIJ: What’s the Neturei Karta minhag when hearing hamas in Megillah Esther on Purim

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Most Jews when they hear the Megillah Esther being read on Purim spin gragers and go “boo Hamas” when hearing Hamas’ name mentioned. Do Neturei Karta Jews not have this minhag?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: They boo when the word מדינה is read. (Old joke, probably older than I am.)

Comment: They boo Mordechai and cheer for Haman.

Comment: Tehillim 11:5 - ה'צַדִּיק יִ֫בְחָן וְרָשָׁע וְאֹהֵב חָמָס שָֽׂנְאָה נַפְשֽׁוֹ

Comment: (I don't think it says that word in the megillah. It says מס, which means taxes, and people boo that.)

Comment: They rush the bimah and try to join what they think is a call for recruitment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps they don't even listen to the Megila, as they don't want to be part of a story where Jews are victorious.